# Which one of these two sequences is random, and which one is not?

Tags: probability-theory, randomness

We let $\alpha = \alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\ldots$ be an infinite random sequence (under the uniform measure) where $\alpha_i$ may be $1$ or $0$, and then define the boolean function $B_k$:

$$
B_k(\alpha_1\ldots\alpha_k) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 \text{ if at least } \lceil k/2 \rceil \text{ of its inputs are } 1
\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then we define two sequences:

$$B_3(\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3)B_3(\alpha_4\alpha_5\alpha_6)B_3(\alpha_7\alpha_8\alpha_9)\ldots$$
$$B_4(\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4)B_4(\alpha_5\alpha_6\alpha_7\alpha_8)B_4(\alpha_9\alpha_{10}\alpha_{11}\alpha_{12})\ldots$$

Which one of these two sequences is ([algorithmically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence)) random, and why? I should note that apparently there is an obvious measure-theoretic fact that gives away which one is not random.

Comment: If $k=2n+1$ then $P(B_k = 1) < P(B_k = 0)$. Isn't that sufficient, informally?

Comment: maybe a related [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27578/can-a-transcendental-number-like-e-or-pi-be-compressed-as-not-algorithmical)

Comment: Isnt each $B_k$ sequence the same as the partial sum sequence of $a_i$'s (or more correctly the difference of 2 partial sum sequences)?

Comment: i can also give another type of answer in sigal procesing terms. Each $B_k$ sequence acts as lowpass filter (filtering away high frequencies) as a result because random noise has especially high frequencies, each $B_k$ should be progresively less random (eventually equal a sequence of 1's).

Comment: @OllieFord, I think you've got that backwards.  It's fine for odd $k$; the problem you mention arises for even $k$.

Comment: @D.W. I think you noticed I was wrong, but corrected the wrong part? Isn't it fine for even, but I meant $>$, not $<$? Note it's $\alpha_1...\alpha_k$, not $\alpha_0...\alpha_k$.

Comment: @OllieFord, yup, you are quite right.

Comment: They are certainly both random in *some* way; what kind of distribution do you (not) want?

Comment: @Raphael I was interested in *algorithmic randomness*, i.e. Martin-Loef Randomness.

Comment: @Newb According to the Wikipedia article you link, there are multiple possibilities and the default is a convention of the field. You should be careful using such conventions here without clarification -- not every reader is a domain expert.

Comment: @Raphael, as per your comment, i have in mind the "kolmogorov-complexity" formulation of algorithmicaly random sequence (similar to the re-formulation of Martin-Loef). It states that an algorithmicaly random sequence cannot be compressed more than its actual length, sth that both sequences given in question possess (but not in the limit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sequence is not random.  Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$ be random, iid Bernoulli $1/2$ random variables.  Let $\beta = B_4(\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \alpha_3 \alpha_4)$.

What is the distribution of the random variable $\beta$?  Answer: $\beta=1$ if at least two of the $\alpha$'s are $1$, so $\Pr[\beta=1] = 11/16$.

In other words, $\beta$ is biased towards $1$.  It follows that the second sequence is not algorithmically random: it is a set of independent Bernoulli random variables with $p=11/16$, i.e., the outcome of an infinite sequence of tosses of a biased coin.

Comment: All right! That makes perfect sense. Thanks. Do you have any reasoning as to why the first sequence is random?

Comment: By contrast, it would be because $B_3$ is "fair": there are 4 3-bit sequences that $B_3$ maps to 1 and 4 3-bit sequences that it maps to 0, so assuming the original sequence is random, $Pr[B=1] = Pr[B=0] = \frac12$.

Comment: i dont agree with this, it just states that the random variable $\beta$ does not have equal p1 and p2 probabilties. Why a random variable with P1 = 1/3 and P0 = 2/3, not be considered random? Why r.v's with a different distribution are not random (a gaussian rv is not random, it is biased towards the mean)?

Comment: In fact i am posting a question (soon?) addresing the relaton between probabilistic and algorithmic randomness (per the other question i linked in the comments)

Comment: I think you're right, while both are random in a sense, algorithmically random is not the same as probabilistically random. As I am not an expert on algorithmic randomness, that's really I can say. I would be interested for an elaboration of these points as well.